# tfs server side plugins information

Tags: tfs, tfs-sdk

Can any one let me know if  the request coming to tfs  is like this  "http://test-test-app1:8080/tfs/_apis/distributedtask/pools/etc etc" if the url contains "/_apis/distributedtask/pools" which all types of request would send a URL like this to TFS, i mean

- If I create a workitem will the request to TFS will have  "/_apis/distributedtask/pools" ?
- If I create build will the request to TFS will have  "/_apis/distributedtask/pools" ?
- In what all scenarios does the URL contains "/_apis/distributedtask/pools" ?

I have written TFS server side plugins and i want ignore if the server plugins receives a url which contains "/_apis/distributedtask/pools" but i do not want to affect the validations which i am doing in the plugins like

1. Validation fields in VS
2. Controlling the users who can upload a process template or a workitem witd

I do no want to affect these things.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you can't just ignore the `/_apis/distributedtask/pools` in the URL.

And there can be others different with pools such as  `/_apis/distributedtask/hubs`

pools are for the action with build.

And if you create a workitem will not the request to have `"/_apis/distributedtask/pools`

Answer (score 0):

No, the URL for each request type is different. "/_apis/distributedtask/pools" is used for vNext Build Agent Service. You can ignore it if your plugin does not need to track the information for Build Agent Service.

You can use Fiddler to check the URL for each request type:

vNext Build Agent Service:
[image]

Create Work Item:
[image]

Queue New Build:
[image]